# Email php erro , n consigo de jeito nenhum

Tags: php, html, email

Renovando perguntar , usei o PHPMailer em um arquivo meu php , como coloco ele no meu site(html), para as pessoas me mandarem msgs para o gmail...

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma, evitando maiores frustrações.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro acontece porque você está tentando usar o $this fora de uma classe, recomento você pesquisar sobre PHP e orientação a objetos para entender o uso do $this.

Além disso para usar a função mail no Windows você vai precisar configurar algumas coisas a mais no seu ambiente, por conta disso muitos usam a lib PHPMailer no lugar da função mail.

Comment: vou tentar usar o PHPMailer.. se funcionar dou o accept

Comment: Comentei sobre o PHPMailer, mas o erro no seu código é por conta de usar o $this fora de um contexto de classe. Você entendeu o significado de usar $this?

Comment: Estou em curso de html , sei o básico de php. Estou vendo muitos videos e sites sobre fazer email do site direto para o meu gmail. Sobre o $this estava dando um erro de porta 25 de email e acabei colocando la , mas não , eu nao entendi Jhonny.

Comment: Como você é bem iniciante, vou te recomendar esse vídeo aqui para você conseguir realizar o seu objetivo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seoweg-PfEM

Comment: Jhonny Freire fiz  youtube.com/watch?v=seoweg-PfEM , certinho ; e agora como faço para botar no meu site oq vai mandar para o email ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/8d7vRMD a foto do powershell a unica coisa q deu errado , ja mexi no path do windows e no powershell antes . talvez seja isso

Comment: "ibb.co/8d7vRMD a foto do powershell a unica coisa q deu errado , ja mexi no path do windows e no powershell antes . talvez seja isso" posso usar o xxamp ao invés.

Comment: não manjo nada de php :(

Comment: Isso certamente está relacionado a forma que você instalou o PHP no Windows, quase certo que seja configuração nas variáveis de ambiente feitas errado. Aconselho a abrir um novo tópico  aqui no atackoverflow para esse problema em específico, Outras pessoas com esse problema poderão encontrar sua pergunta e se beneficiar da solução.

Comment: vou abrir sobre o powershell , mas me tira uma duvida dps que ajeita o PHPmailer como faço meu codigo para enviar as info colocadas no meu 'site' ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/rk276V1 <<<<<<< POWERSHELL AJEITADO

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=seoweg-PfEM  tudo que esse site falou de phpmailer e powershell eu fiz

Comment: ja to com os codigos PHP tudo arrumado e agora oq eu faço, para botar num formulario no site ?

Comment: foi mal pelo outro post ,apaguei sem dar o accept , mas nesse n vou cometer o erro